# dart unitest suite never ending on drone.io

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, dart

I have continuous integration on drone.io for my dart projects, normally there aren't any issues with this, except for actual bugs in my code, but my latest tests are all passing and the test suite reports it completed successfully, but the drone.io test runner never exists it just keeps running until it times out and reports build failed. Has anyone else had anything something familiar to this? or no how to fix it? [here is the build](https://drone.io/github.com/0xor1/purity/12) if you kick off a new build from the big-refactor-and-enhancement branch that is where it has this odd behaviour.

Comment: I couldn't find any unit tests in your GitHub repo. Are there any?  
What does your drone.io build script look like?

Comment: the unit tests only exist on the branch big-refactor-and-enhancement, the build script is just `pub install` `dart test/unit/purity_test.dart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at your code, I would bet that [the server launched under the cover](https://github.com/0xor1/purity/blob/big-refactor-and-enhancement/test/unit/purity_test.dart#L63) is not shut down. You should add a `close()` method on it and call it in [_tearDown()](https://github.com/0xor1/purity/blob/big-refactor-and-enhancement/test/unit/purity_test.dart#L76-L78).

Comment: hmmm I guess you are probably correct, I'll try doing as you suggest and see if it fixes the situation, I just assumed after I nulled out everything it would all be free for garbage collection, though I guess the `PurityAppSession` and `PurityClientCore` are still tethered together via two active `Stream<String>`